# DirectX11 - Buffer size of instanced vertices, with various size

Tags: directx-11

With DirectX/C++, suppose you are drawing the same model many times to the screen. You can do this with DrawIndexedInstanced(). You need to set the size of the instance buffer when you create it:

```
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC_instance.ByteWidth = sizeof(struct_with_instance_data)* instance_count;
```

If the instance_count can vary between a low and high value, is it customary to create the buffer with the max value (max_instance_count)? And only draw what is required.
Wouldn't that permanently use a lot of memory?
Recreating the buffer is a slow solution?

What are good methods?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All methods have pros and cons.

1. Create max.count — as you pointed out you’ll consume extra memory.
2. Create some initial count, and implement exponential growth — you can OOM in runtime, also growing large buffers may cause spikes in the profiler.

There’s other way which may or may not work for you depending on the application. You can create reasonably large fixed-size buffer, to render more instances call DrawIndexedInstanced multiple times in a loop, replacing the data in the buffer between calls. Will work well if the source data is generated in runtime from something else, you’ll need to rework that part to produce fixed-size (except the last one) batches instead of the complete buffer. Won’t work if the data in the buffer needs to persist across frames, e.g. if you update it with a compute shader.